# Sequences in the cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set with the cofinite topology. I must prove that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence and $x_n \ne x_m$ for all $n \ne m$, then any $x$ is the limit of $x_n$.

Can anyone give me some explained examples on this? I don't get how a sequence works in this topology.

Answer (score 2):

If $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence such that all $x_n$ are different, we know that $A:=\{x_n \mid n \in \Bbb N\}$ is an infinite set.

If $O$ is an open set of $X$ that contains $x$ (so is non-empty) we know that $F:=X\setminus O$ is finite and so $A \cap F$ is finite too and there is some $N$ such that $x_N$ is the point with maximal index in $A \cap F$. It follows that for all $n > N$, $x_n \notin F$ so $x_n \in O$ and so for *any* open neighbourhood $O$ of *any* $x \in X$, a tail of the sequence is in that neighbourhood, and this means *by definition of convergence* that $x_n \to x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in X$ and $U\in \mathcal{T_{X}}$ an open subset containing $x$.. The definition of convergence of sequences states that $(x_n)$ converges to x if for every open set U containing $x$ there $\exists \delta \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\gt \delta x_n\in U$ ..it means that after a finite number of terms of $(x_n)$ all the infinite  remaining terms enter U.. Since the topology here is the cofinite topology then the compliment of every open set U is finite $\implies$ certainly an infinite number of terms of $(x_n)$ enters U. Thus $x$ is a limite of $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x \in X$ and Let $ U $ be an open set such that $x \in U$ then the set $X - U$ is finite. Since $(x_n)$ is injective (by hypotesis) exists an $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \notin X - U \forall n > m$

Thus exists an $m \in \mathbb N$ such that  $x_n \in  U \forall n > m$, and by limit definition  $(x_n)$ converges to $x$